# Strange behaviour, initialize a function pointer with an int?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, casting, initialization, function-pointers

Accidentally, I found this code compiles on VS2012.

```
typedef void (*func)();
func f = func(12);
```

`f` is initialized with an integer 12 as its address.
as far as I know, cast from integer to a function pointer is valid, which looks like this:

```
func f = (func)12;
```

while the statement `func(12)` looks more like a constructor, so I tried this one:

```
func f(12);
```

and it failed compilation.

---

```
func f = (func)12  //ok, cast           1
func f = func(12); //ok, what?          2
func f(12);        //failed             3
func f = 12;       //failed             4
```

so my question is:

1. What is the real underlying syntax of `func(12)`, is it a cast or initialization?
2. How comes to initialize a function pointer with an integer?
3. Should the 4th expression compiles? What about the 3rd one?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. In general, an int cannot be casted to a function pointer or vice versa. In 32 bit Windows, both happen to have 32 bit, but e.g. in 64 bit Windows a pointer is 64 bit, of course, and an int is still 32 bit.

Comment: @cdoubleplusgood I'm not actually trying to cast an integer to a function pointer, I just want to figure out why this compiles: func f = func(12);

Comment: could be that there is a function named `func` which takes an integer and returns a function of type `void function_name()`

Comment: @Smac89 typedef void (*func)();

Comment: Really weird behaviour indeed. Take a look at [this](http://ideone.com/SdDRvJ)

Comment: @Smac89 interesting, that's a function pointer initialized with a comma expression, which is identical to func('c'), and dereference on a function pointer does nothing. so it seems that it's valid to initialize a function pointer with any integral type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through these one by one:

```
func f = (func)12  //ok, cast           1
```

Here, you are casting the integer value 12 to a function pointer using an explicit cast.  This cast isn't allowed as a normal implicit conversion, but it is acceptable because C++ can use a `reinterpret_cast` to cast integer and pointer types to one another.  It's just not safe or portable.

```
func f = func(12); //ok, what?          2
```

This is a different syntax for the above.  The syntaxes `(type) value` and `type(value)` are identical as long as `type` is a primitive type.

```
func f(12);        //failed             3
```

Here, you are trying to create an object of type `func` initialized to the value 12.  This style of object declaration is only permissible if either

- There's a constructor that can do the conversion (not applicable; `func` is a primitive type), or
- There is an implicit conversion defined between the source and definition types (not applicable; there is no implicit conversion between integral and pointer types).

Therefore, the compiler reports an error.

```
func f = 12;       //failed             4
```

This only works if there is a non-explicit conversion constructor available to do the cast (not applicable), or if there is an implicit conversion defined between the source and destination types (again, not applicable because there is no conversion defined between integers and function pointer types).  Therefore, you get an error.

Hope this helps!